# How to implement shooting and collision

Tags: node.js, canvas, socket.io

I'm looking for solution how can I implement shooting to my game. I'd like to have shooting on mouse direction sync it with other players and when bullet collide with other player he dies and respawn.
Here's my code:
Server.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

    http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
    console.log('Serwer wystartował na porcie: 3000');

//obsługa połączeń
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

var gracze = [];

//funkcja tworząca graczy
function nowyGracz() {
    this.nazwa;
    this.id = 1;
    this.x = Math.random() * 500;
    this.y =  Math.random() * 500;
    //losowe kolory
    var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
    this.kolor = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", 0.5)";

    this.promien = 30;
    this.predkosc =  2;

    return {'nazwa' : this.nazwa,"x" : this.x,"y" : this.y,"kolor" : this.kolor, "promien" : this.promien,"predkosc" : this.predkosc}
}


//połączenie do serwera i obsluga polaczen kazdego nowego gracza
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var gracz = new nowyGracz(); //nowy gracz
    gracze.push(gracz); //wrzuc gracza do tablicy

    //tablica z graczami
    socket.broadcast.emit('currentUsers', gracze);
    socket.emit('welcome', gracz, gracze);

        //rozłączono
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        gracze.splice(gracze.indexOf(gracz), 1);
        console.log(gracze);
        socket.broadcast.emit('graczWyszedl', gracze);
    });

    socket.on('wcisniety', function(przycisk){
        if(przycisk === 38 || przycisk === 87){
            gracz.y -= gracz.predkosc;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
        } 
        if(przycisk === 40 || przycisk === 83){
            gracz.y += gracz.predkosc;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
        } 
        if(przycisk === 37 || przycisk === 65){
            gracz.x -= gracz.predkosc;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
        } 
        if(przycisk === 39 || przycisk === 68){
            gracz.x += gracz.predkosc;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', gracze);
        }
    });
});
```

When player join he appears on screen etc. But I have no idea how to implement shooting. Hope for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To build a Multi-player on-line game(especially Massively Multi-player Online Fast Paced Game,such as PUBG), we should 'calculate' the collision between bullets and players, either on the client side, or the server side.

To do this on the client side, you'll need a 'physics engine' on the client side, if you are using HTML5 to build your game, you may try the 'Phaser.js' game engine.  Due to network and other issues, Player A may think that he kills Player B, But player B may think that the bullet misses, we usually handle this by using the technique 'Frame Alignment'.

To do the calculation on the server side, you usually need to write your own physics engine, user send 'actions' to server, server calculate the position of each user and each bullet, server determine which user dies.  This technique is called 'State Synchronization'.

That means, to build MMS games, decide which technique you want to use first, I would suggest using a Game/Physics engine and do calculation on the client side,  otherwise if the number of players grow, you'll need more and more game servers.